# Gauge Scale not Working

Tags: android

Hi I actually followed this link for creating a gauge view.

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

But when I run the code in the emulator, the readings of the gauge turn out to be zero and I am not able to figure out why. Any clues on what could have gone wrong? I printed the "i" values of the function drawscale and they turn out to be fine but the reading in the gaugeview when I run the emulator always is zero.

```
      package com.mindtherobot.samples.thermometer;


      import java.util.List;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
     import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
     import android.graphics.Canvas;
     import android.graphics.Color;
     import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
     import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
     import android.graphics.Matrix;
     import android.graphics.Paint;
     import android.graphics.Path;
     import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
     import android.graphics.RectF;
     import android.graphics.Shader;
     import android.graphics.Typeface;
     import android.hardware.Sensor;
     import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
     import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
     import android.hardware.SensorManager;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;

    public final class Thermometer extends View implements SensorEventListener {

private static final String TAG = Thermometer.class.getSimpleName();

private Handler handler;

// drawing tools
private RectF rimRect;
private Paint rimPaint;
private Paint rimCirclePaint;

private RectF faceRect;
private Bitmap faceTexture;
private Paint facePaint;
private Paint rimShadowPaint;

private Paint scalePaint;
private RectF scaleRect;

private Paint titlePaint;   
private Path titlePath;

private Paint logoPaint;
private Bitmap logo;
private Matrix logoMatrix;
private float logoScale;

private Paint handPaint;
private Path handPath;
private Paint handScrewPaint;

private Paint backgroundPaint; 
// end drawing tools

private Bitmap background; // holds the cached static part

// scale configuration


private int totalNotches = 100;
private int incrementPerLargeNotch = 10;
private int incrementPerSmallNotch = 2;
private float degreesPerNotch = 360.0f / totalNotches;  

private int scaleCenterValue = 40; // the one in the top center (12 o'clock)
private int scaleMinValue = -30;
private int scaleMaxValue = 110;

// hand dynamics -- all are angular expressed in F degrees
private boolean handInitialized = false;
private float handPosition = scaleCenterValue;
private float handTarget = scaleCenterValue;
private float handVelocity = 0.0f;
private float handAcceleration = 0.0f;
private long lastHandMoveTime = -1L;


public Thermometer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public Thermometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public Thermometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    attachToSensor();
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    detachFromSensor();
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
    Parcelable superState = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);

    handInitialized = bundle.getBoolean("handInitialized");
    handPosition = bundle.getFloat("handPosition");
    handTarget = bundle.getFloat("handTarget");
    handVelocity = bundle.getFloat("handVelocity");
    handAcceleration = bundle.getFloat("handAcceleration");
    lastHandMoveTime = bundle.getLong("lastHandMoveTime");
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    state.putParcelable("superState", superState);
    state.putBoolean("handInitialized", handInitialized);
    state.putFloat("handPosition", handPosition);
    state.putFloat("handTarget", handTarget);
    state.putFloat("handVelocity", handVelocity);
    state.putFloat("handAcceleration", handAcceleration);
    state.putLong("lastHandMoveTime", lastHandMoveTime);
    return state;
}

private void init() {
    handler = new Handler();

    initDrawingTools();
}

private String getTitle() {
    return "mindtherobot.com";
}

private SensorManager getSensorManager() {
    return (SensorManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);       
}

private void attachToSensor() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = getSensorManager();

    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);
    if (sensors.size() > 0) {
        Sensor sensor = sensors.get(0);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, handler);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "No temperature sensor found");
    }       
}

private void detachFromSensor() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = getSensorManager();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

private void initDrawingTools() {
    rimRect = new RectF(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.9f, 0.9f);

    // the linear gradient is a bit skewed for realism
    rimPaint = new Paint();
    rimPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    rimPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0.40f, 0.0f, 0.60f, 1.0f, 
                                       Color.rgb(0xf0, 0xf5, 0xf0),
                                       Color.rgb(0x30, 0x31, 0x30),
                                       Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));     

    rimCirclePaint = new Paint();
    rimCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    rimCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    rimCirclePaint.setColor(Color.argb(0x4f, 0x33, 0x36, 0x33));
    rimCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.005f);

    float rimSize = 0.02f;
    faceRect = new RectF();
    faceRect.set(rimRect.left + rimSize, rimRect.top + rimSize, 
             rimRect.right - rimSize, rimRect.bottom - rimSize);        

    faceTexture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), 
               R.drawable.plastic);
    BitmapShader paperShader = new BitmapShader(faceTexture, 
                                                Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, 
                                                Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    Matrix paperMatrix = new Matrix();
    facePaint = new Paint();
    facePaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paperMatrix.setScale(1.0f / faceTexture.getWidth(), 
                         1.0f / faceTexture.getHeight());
    paperShader.setLocalMatrix(paperMatrix);
    facePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    facePaint.setShader(paperShader);

    rimShadowPaint = new Paint();
    rimShadowPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(0.5f, 0.5f, faceRect.width() / 2.0f, 
               new int[] { 0x00000000, 0x00000500, 0x50000500 },
               new float[] { 0.96f, 0.96f, 0.99f },
               Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    rimShadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    scalePaint = new Paint();
    scalePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    scalePaint.setColor(0x9f004d0f);
    scalePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.005f);
    scalePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    scalePaint.setTextSize(0.045f);
    scalePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
    scalePaint.setTextScaleX(0.8f);
    scalePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);        

    float scalePosition = 0.10f;
    scaleRect = new RectF();
    scaleRect.set(faceRect.left + scalePosition, faceRect.top + scalePosition,
                  faceRect.right - scalePosition, faceRect.bottom - scalePosition);

    titlePaint = new Paint();
    titlePaint.setColor(0xaf946109);
    titlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    titlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    titlePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    titlePaint.setTextSize(0.05f);
    titlePaint.setTextScaleX(0.8f);

    titlePath = new Path();
    titlePath.addArc(new RectF(0.24f, 0.24f, 0.76f, 0.76f), -180.0f, -180.0f);

    logoPaint = new Paint();
    logoPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    logoMatrix = new Matrix();
    logoScale = (1.0f / logo.getWidth()) * 0.3f;;
    logoMatrix.setScale(logoScale, logoScale);

    handPaint = new Paint();
    handPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    handPaint.setColor(0xff392f2c);     
    handPaint.setShadowLayer(0.01f, -0.005f, -0.005f, 0x7f000000);
    handPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);   

    handPath = new Path();
    handPath.moveTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.2f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.010f, 0.5f + 0.2f - 0.007f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.010f, 0.5f + 0.2f - 0.007f);
    handPath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.2f);
    handPath.addCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.025f, Path.Direction.CW);

    handScrewPaint = new Paint();
    handScrewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    handScrewPaint.setColor(0xff493f3c);
    handScrewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Width spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
    Log.d(TAG, "Height spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
    int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

    int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

    setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
}

private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) {
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        return size;
    } else { // (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        return getPreferredSize();
    } 
}

// in case there is no size specified
private int getPreferredSize() {
    return 300;
}

private void drawRim(Canvas canvas) {
    // first, draw the metallic body
    canvas.drawOval(rimRect, rimPaint);
    // now the outer rim circle
    canvas.drawOval(rimRect, rimCirclePaint);
}

private void drawFace(Canvas canvas) {      
    canvas.drawOval(faceRect, facePaint);
    // draw the inner rim circle
    canvas.drawOval(faceRect, rimCirclePaint);
    // draw the rim shadow inside the face
    canvas.drawOval(faceRect, rimShadowPaint);
}

private void drawScale(Canvas canvas) {
    // Draw a large notch every large increment, and a small
    // notch every small increment.

    canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);

    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNotches; ++i) {
        float y1 = scaleRect.top;
        float y2 = y1 - 0.015f;
        float y3 = y1 - 0.025f;
        System.out.println("The value of i is "+i);

        int value = notchToValue(i);
        System.out.println("The value of value is "+value);
        if (i % (incrementPerLargeNotch/incrementPerSmallNotch) == 0) {
            System.out.println("inside loop i"+i);
            if (value >= scaleMinValue && value <= scaleMaxValue) {
                // draw a nick
                canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y3, scalePaint);

                String valueString = Integer.toString(value);
                System.out.println("the value of value string is "+valueString);
                // Draw the text 0.15 away from y3 which is the long nick.
                canvas.drawText(valueString, 0.5f, y3 - 0.015f, scalePaint);
            }
        }
        else{
            if (value >= scaleMinValue && value <= scaleMaxValue) {
                // draw a nick
                canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, scalePaint);
            }
        }

        canvas.rotate(degreesPerNotch, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
    canvas.restore();       
}

private int notchToValue(int value) {
    int rawValue = ((value < totalNotches / 2) ? value : (value - totalNotches)) * incrementPerSmallNotch;
    int shiftedValue = rawValue + scaleCenterValue;
    return shiftedValue;
}

private float valueToAngle(float value) {
    return (value - scaleCenterValue) / 2.0f * degreesPerNotch;
}
private void drawTitle(Canvas canvas) {
    String title = getTitle();
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(title, titlePath, 0.0f,0.0f, titlePaint);             
}

private void drawLogo(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.translate(0.5f - logo.getWidth() * logoScale / 2.0f, 
                     0.5f - logo.getHeight() * logoScale / 2.0f);

    int color = 0x00000000;
    float position = getRelativeTemperaturePosition();
    if (position < 0) {
        color |= (int) ((0xf0) * -position); // blue
    } else {
        color |= ((int) ((0xf0) * position)) << 16; // red          
    }
    //Log.d(TAG, "*** " + Integer.toHexString(color));
    LightingColorFilter logoFilter = new LightingColorFilter(0xff338822, color);
    logoPaint.setColorFilter(logoFilter);

    canvas.drawBitmap(logo, logoMatrix, logoPaint);
    canvas.restore();       
}

private void drawHand(Canvas canvas) {
    if (handInitialized) {
        float handAngle = valueToAngle(handPosition);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(handAngle, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        canvas.drawPath(handPath, handPaint);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.01f, handScrewPaint);
    }
}

private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    if (background == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Background not created");
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, backgroundPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawBackground(canvas);

    float scale = (float) getWidth();       
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);

    drawLogo(canvas);
    drawHand(canvas);

    canvas.restore();

    if (handNeedsToMove()) {
        moveHand();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Size changed to " + w + "x" + h);

    regenerateBackground();
}

private void regenerateBackground() {
    // free the old bitmap
    if (background != null) {
        background.recycle();
    }

    background = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(background);
    float scale = (float) getWidth();       
    backgroundCanvas.scale(scale, scale);

    drawRim(backgroundCanvas);
    drawFace(backgroundCanvas);
    drawScale(backgroundCanvas);
    drawTitle(backgroundCanvas);        
}

private boolean handNeedsToMove() {
    return Math.abs(handPosition - handTarget) > 0.01f;
}

private void moveHand() {
    if (! handNeedsToMove()) {
        return;
    }

    if (lastHandMoveTime != -1L) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float delta = (currentTime - lastHandMoveTime) / 1000.0f;

        float direction = Math.signum(handVelocity);
        if (Math.abs(handVelocity) < 90.0f) {
            handAcceleration = 5.0f * (handTarget - handPosition);
        } else {
            handAcceleration = 0.0f;
        }
        handPosition += handVelocity * delta;
        handVelocity += handAcceleration * delta;
        if ((handTarget - handPosition) * direction < 0.01f * direction) {
            handPosition = handTarget;
            handVelocity = 0.0f;
            handAcceleration = 0.0f;
            lastHandMoveTime = -1L;
        } else {
            lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();              
        }
        invalidate();
    } else {
        lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        moveHand();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.values.length > 0) {
        float temperatureC = sensorEvent.values[0];
        //Log.i(TAG, "*** Temperature: " + temperatureC);

        float temperatureF = (9.0f / 5.0f) * temperatureC + 32.0f;
        setHandTarget(temperatureF);
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Empty sensor event received");
    }
}

private float getRelativeTemperaturePosition() {
    if (handPosition < scaleCenterValue) {
        return - (scaleCenterValue - handPosition) / (float) (scaleCenterValue - scaleMinValue);
    } else {
        return (handPosition - scaleCenterValue) / (float) (scaleMaxValue - scaleCenterValue);
    }
}

private void setHandTarget(float temperature) {
    if (temperature < scaleMinValue) {
        temperature = scaleMinValue;
    } else if (temperature > scaleMaxValue) {
        temperature = scaleMaxValue;
    }
    handTarget = temperature;
    handInitialized = true;
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I encountered the same problem yesterday.

What I believe the OP is describing is that all the number values displayed on the scale  appear to be `0`. Setting `setLinearText(true)` to `scalePaint` corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

whats goes wrong? 
if you mean why the thermometer not displaying any values, its because program is using SensorManager to receive TEMPERATURE values.
Since the Emulator don't have any, the value returned is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I added this line to `initDrawingTools()` method after all the sets of `scalePaint`.

```
scalePaint.setLinearText(true);
```

And it worked!